# Autosave to database after timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timeout, autosave

I want to perform autosave when a user fills out a form in a React component. The ajax call should be triggered when 3 seconds has passed since last `onChange` event.

My code below is inspired from [an instructive article](http://codetunnel.io/how-to-implement-autosave-in-your-web-app/) which shows how to accomplish this with `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`. But I'm doing something wrong in my React implementation - the 3 sec delay isn't respected when typing.

**Any ideas what's wrong here? Or is my thinking all together wrong about how to solve this?**

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isSaved: false
    };
    this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
    this.saveToDatabase = this.saveToDatabase.bind(this);
  }
  saveToDatabase() {
    var timeoutId;
    this.setState({isSaved: false});
    if (timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    };
    timeoutId = setTimeout( ()  => {
        // Make ajax call to save data.
        this.setState({isSaved: true});
    }, 3000);
  }
  handleUserInput(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
    this.saveToDatabase();
  }
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.isSaved ? 'Saved' : 'Not saved'}
      // My form.
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `saveToDatabase` method you are defining a new and **undefined** `timeoutId` variable every time the method is called. That's why the `if` statement never gets called.

Instead, you need to scope out the variable and create a class data property in the constructor.

```
 constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
     isSaved: false
   };
   this.timeoutId = null;
   this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
   this.saveToDatabase = this.saveToDatabase.bind(this);
 } 

 saveToDatabase() {
   this.setState({isSaved: false});
   if (this.timeoutId) {
     clearTimeout(this.timeoutId)
   };
   this.timeoutId = setTimeout( ()  => {
     // Make ajax call to save data.
     this.setState({isSaved: true});
   }, 3000);
 }
```